# Graph Theory that how to find shortest path from source A to Destination B as explained below

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

Background:   You have a map stored as a undirected graph. Edges present streets or highways.  There are two kinds of edges - green and red- and both kind of edges have weights.  The weight of an edge is the distance that edge represents.  Red edges represent represent toll roads, if you cross a red edge you pay as many cents as the weight of the edge.  For example the red edge (r, 20)  is 20 miles long and costs you 20 cents.  All the green edges are free.

Problem:   Write an algorithm to find the cheapest/shortest path from city S to city D. Cost has higher priority than distance. For example a free 500-mile long path is better than a 300-mile long path that costs  70 cents!

he problem is exactly the shortest path problem if all edges are green.  Also if there is a connected path from S to V with all red edges removed, then it is the shortest path problem. What if S and V are  not connected with all red edges removed?  Then maybe insert cheapest red edge, if S and V are  connected with it then again the problem becomes the shortest path problem. So now I found three simple cases:
     1. All green graph.
         2. Graph with  a path from S to V when all red edges are connected.
         3. Graph with a path from S to V when cheapest red edge is connected.
After this point it get a little difficult, or does it???

Comment: the main-problem here is that you still haven't defined the modality of priority. eg. is there a breakeven-point, like "a route with length `n` may cost at most `n * x`ct to be as good as a `n * y` long route that is free". If a free route is always better than one that costs a bit no matter of the length, this should be pretty straight forward

Comment: Can any one try with little idea of algorithm which can make little easy way for me! thanks. What you guys are discussing is that i know already. And i have also written in the question .. you all are just repeating it.

Comment: no you haven't. Finding an algorithm for the shortest-path-problem shouldn't be the problem. But since the question doesn't even properly describe the problem it's pretty hard to give a better answer than MTOs, which is pretty good. Actually MTOs algorithm presents a complete solution to your problem

Answer (score 2):

> Cost has higher priority than distance. For example a free 500-mile long path is better than a 300-mile long path that costs 70 cents!

Run [Djikstra's algorithm using a min-priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Using_a_priority_queue) where the routes explored are prioritised by, firstly, lowest cost then, secondly, lowest distance.

Since all-green routes will have zero-cost then these will be explored first looking for the shortest distance route; if there are no zero-cost routes then, and only then, will red routes be explored in priority order of lowest cost.

Comment: Can any one try with little idea of algorithm which can make little easy way for me! thanks. What you guys are discussing is that i know already. And i have also written in the question .. you all are just repeating it.

Answer (score 0):

Just run a "little modified" Dijkstra on this graph with setting weight of each edge to its price. You find all low-cost solutions with it and then you choose the shortest one.

The only real problem is that you can have edges with cost 0, but it can be solved - if you are in situation where you can open multiple nodes (they would have all same price), select the one with the lowest distance.

---

The only difference to classic Dijkstra.

In dijkstra in each step you open the node with lowest cost. If there are multiple nodes with lowest cost, you just choose any of them (it really does not matter).

In this case, if you have multiple nodes with lowest cost, you choose the one with lowest distance. If there are multiple nodes with lowest cost and lowest distance, you can open any of them (it really does not matter).

---

This solves every case you mentioned.

Comment: Can any one try with little idea of algorithm which can make little easy way for me! thanks. What you guys are discussing is that i know already. And i have also written in the question .. you all are just repeating it.

Comment: @user3581144 - you wrote you have problem with solving it. I wrote you complete solution. If you use this modified Dijkstra, every single graph will be solved properly. I do not know what else you want...?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more about how you handle the data than the algorithm. Let me propose this. Say the sum of the length of all the paths is less than 1'000'000. Then I can encode the cost and length as cost * 1'000'000 + length. Now you have a simple graph where you only have one metric to optimize.

I think it's clear that the most important thing the search is going to optimize is cost (since we multiplied it by 1'000'000) and that for paths of equal cost the length is going to be the deciding factor.

To actually implement this you don't need the assumption or to conversion I just did. You can keep cost and length everywhere and simply modify your comparisons to first compare the cost and only when it's a tie to compare the lengths.

Comment: Can any one try with little idea of algorithm which can make little easy way for me! thanks. What you guys are discussing is that i know already. And i have also written in the question .. you all are just repeating it.